# how to rotate div on slider left right

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I rotate this `div` using the `slider` and JQuery?

Sliding left should rotate left and sliding right should rotate right.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inner" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:black;"></div>
<input type="range" value="0" min="-360" max="360" />
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also `extend` to generate `rotate` function

```js
var rotation = 0;
jQuery.fn.rotate = function(degrees) {
    $(this).css({'transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)'});
    return $(this);
};

$('.slider').on('input',function() {
    rotation = parseInt($(this).val());
    $('.rotate').rotate(rotation);
});
```

```css
.rotate{
  background-color:black;
  margin:20px 20px 20px 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="rotate" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-
color:black; display:block; "></div>
<br/>

<input type="range" class="slider" value="0" min="-360" max="360" />
```